# Windows batch equivalent of bash's set -e

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file

Is there a Windows batch equivalent to bash's `set -e`, which causes the shell to exit immediately if a command fails with nonzero exit status (except in places where it's expected like in an `if` statement)? I gets tiring to put `if errorlevel 1 exit 1` after every single line.

Comment: Have you considered `cmd /C 'command'`?  It executes the command and then terminates.  Try `cmd /?` for more options.

Comment: I am using `cmd /c`. This doesn't have the behavior I am looking for, though.

Comment: Is there a way you could group the commands in an `if` block in the script?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: You can put `|| exit /b 1` after every command. It seems there is nothing better than this.

Answer (score 2):

To specify more than one command on the command prompt line by using the ampersand character as a command separator:

```
dir & pause
```

For conditional execution of your command using two other command separators. If you separate two command using a double ampersand (&&), then the second command will be executed only if the first command runs successfully:

```
dir && pause
```

If you use a double bar (||) as command separator, then the second command will only be executed if the first command fails:

```
dir Nonsensual-mix || pause
```

Therefore you could use next:

```
your_command || exit 1
```

Comment: I understand that this is a useful implementation, but is it the case that there is no solution that can be achieved without modifying every line that _might_ fail?

Comment: Like in question's comments above: `exit /b 1` - it's not polite to kill somebody's command window just because he happened to run our script.

Comment: @blong - looks like there isn't. So the Continuous Integration servers like CC.Net run it in some custom way. If this is a linear list of lines, this would be easy - you could write one in `.bat` yourself, using `for /f (...)` to read lines from the file. But what about jumps, conditionals (especially with braces and `else` clause), and multi-line (`^`-ending) commands?